# LoadError: incompatible library version cruby.so

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I was facing this error while doing : `rake db:migrate`

I tried with uninstalling and installing the gem cruby many times,but It didn't works.

After switching the database from sqlite to postgres ,the nokogiri dependent libraries need to updated.So that could be the reason

Comment: check the version in your `lock` file and verify with minimum ruby version required on their github page.

Comment: I am using stable ruby version 2.3.1 and the gem is dependent on nokogiri.So that is fine no need to check the version.